# Iterating through fields, which are lists, of an abstract class and passing them to a method of type T?

Tags: c#

I have a class that contains a number of lists:

```
public static class CollectionsClass
{

    public static List<Object1> list1 = new List<Object1>();
    public static List<Object2> list2 = new List<Object2>();
    public static List<Object3> list3 = new List<Object3>();
}
```

I also have a class that performs actions on those lists:

```
public static class ActionClass
{
    private static Random _rnd = new Random();

    public static void PopulateCollections()
    {
        Populate(list1, 0, 1000);
        Populate(list2, 0, 1000);
        Populate(list3, 0, 1000);
    }           

    private static void Populate<T>(List<T> list, int minLimit, int maxLimit) 
        where T: new()
    {
        int popSize = _rnd.Next(minLimit, maxLimit);
        for (int i = 0; i < popSize; i++)
        {
            list.Add(new T());
        }
    }
}
```

Because the number of lists may change, what I would like to do is something like this:

```
    public static void PopulateCollections()
    {
        var fields = typeof(CollectionsClass).GetFields();
        foreach (var field in fields)
        {
            Populate(field, 0, 1000);
        }
    }
```

Unfortunately, that gives me an error:

> The type arguments for method 'app.ActionClass.Populate
>   (System.Collections.Generic.List, int, int)' cannot be inferred
>   from the usage.  Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

So, there's obviously some problem with it not knowing what
type I'm passing... but I thought that it'd be obvious from `field`.

Comment: please show your actual code.your fields (lists) are not static but your class is static.that doesn't compile.

Comment: The variable `field` does not contain a reference to the list, but to information about the field. It "knows" at runtime what the type of the field is, but not at compile time.

Comment: @Selman22 edited the code, can't post the original, sorry

Comment: @KrisVandermotten That's what I figured... any way to get the pointers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the value of a field, for which you have a `FieldInfo` object, using the `GetValue` method. Then you need to call the generic method with the correct type parameter. While that can be constructed using reflection, I suggest you try dynamic programming:

```
public static void PopulateCollections()
{
    var fields = typeof(CollectionsClass).GetFields();
    foreach (var fieldInfo in fields)
    {
        dynamic field = fieldInfo.GetValue(null);
        Populate(field, 0, 1000);
    }
}
```

The code above assumes that those fields are all static, and that there are no other fields than those of type `List<T>`.

Comment: Unfortunately, and I can't figure out why, the lengths of the generated lists are always equal.

Comment: @Dmitry That's because of the way I used `Random`.  I moved it into the context of the class and length vary now.

Comment: Kris, this worked flawlessly and with minimum effort.  Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

I've used reflection for that:

```
public static class CollectionsClass
{
    public static List<Object1> list1 = new List<Object1>();
    public static List<Object2> list2 = new List<Object2>();
    public static List<Object3> list3 = new List<Object3>();
}

public static class ActionClass
{
    private static void Populate<T>(List<T> list, int minLimit, int maxLimit)
        where T : new()
    {
        var rnd = new Random();
        int rndNum = rnd.Next(minLimit, maxLimit);
        for (int i = 0; i < rndNum; i++)
        {
            list.Add(new T());
        }
    }

    public static void PopulateCollections()
    {
        var fields = typeof(CollectionsClass).GetFields(System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Static | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public);
        foreach (var field in fields)
        {
            var method = typeof(ActionClass).GetMethod("Populate", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Static | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic).MakeGenericMethod(field.FieldType.GenericTypeArguments[0]);
            method.Invoke(null, System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Static, null, new object[] { field.GetValue(null), 0, 1000 }, Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture);
        }
    }
}
```